# Problema con swig y python

Tags: python, c, gcc

Hola a todos resulta que estoy queriendo unir mis lenguajes favoritos con swig pero al momento de querer seguir los pasos que vienen en la documentacion resulta que me da el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las intrucciones que uso para compilar y enlazar son la siguientes:

```
swig -python  interface.i
```

Este archivo interface.i contiene dentro los siguiente

```
%module interface
 %{
 extern int My_variable;
 extern FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode);
 extern struct lineas *Lineas();
 extern int fact(int n);
 extern int my_mod(int x, int y);
 extern char *get_time();
 extern int fclose( FILE *fp );
 extern  char **asignar_linea_x(struct lineas *obj,int pos);
 extern PyObject* reservar_matriz_dinamica(PyObject *archivo_user,int pos,int longitud);
 %}

 extern int fclose( FILE *fp );
 extern char **asignar_linea_x(struct lineas *obj,int pos);
extern struct lineas *Lineas();
extern FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode);
extern PyObject* reservar_matriz_dinamica( PyObject *archivo_user,int pos,int longitud);
extern int My_variable;
 extern int fact(int n);
 extern int my_mod(int x, int y);
 extern char *get_time();
```

```
gcc  -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -fpic   -c   $(/usr/bin/python3.10-config  --cflags --includes)  -I/usr/lib/python3.10 -I/usr/include/python3.10  interface_wrap.c interface.c
```

El archivo interface.c contiene dentro lo siguiente

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Python.h>
struct lineas{
  char **linea_x;
    char *cadena_t;
}linea_t,*p_linea_t;


int My_variable=0;
int fact(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    else return n*fact(n-1);
}

int my_mod(int x, int y) {
    return (x%y);
}
char *get_time()
{
    time_t ltime;
    time(&ltime);
    return ctime(&ltime);
}

struct lineas *Lineas() {
  return (struct lineas *) malloc(sizeof(struct lineas));
}
void delete_Vector(struct lineas *obj) {
  free(obj);
}

char **asignar_linea_x(struct lineas *obj,int pos) {
   char **linea_x = (char **)malloc(pos*sizeof(char*));
  return linea_x;
}
FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode);
int fclose( FILE *fp );

PyObject* reservar_matriz_dinamica( PyObject *archivo_user,int pos,int longitud);
PyObject* reservar_matriz_dinamica(PyObject *archivo_user,int pos,int longitud){  
    char *filename;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(archivo_user,"s",&filename)){
        printf("\n ?");
    }    
    FILE *archivo;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(filename); ++i)
    {
        printf("%c\n",*(filename+1) );
    }
}
```

y para enlazar utilizo la siguiente instruccion

```
gcc  -fpic $(/usr/bin/pythfireon3.10-config   --ldflags)   -I/usr/lib/python3.10 -I/usr/include/python3.10  -shared  interface.o interface_wrap.o  -o xploit.so
```

```
import ctypes;  
so=ctypes.CDLL("/home/aldair/Desktop/XPLOIT_RAT_WIFI/ejemplos_swig/xploit.so"); 
#Hasta aqui todo bien
```

Pero en el metodo reservar_matriz dinamica me da el error de la imagen pienso que se debe al petodo que utiizo en el archivo interface.c el que tiene por nombre PyArg_ParseTuple()   si alguien me puede decir como funciona este metodo ademas aclaro que estoy utilizando GNU/LINUX MAS CONCRETAMENTE BLACKARCH se preguntara porque esta distro pero es para un proyecto que estoy desarrollando y por el puro a fan de querer unir mis dos lenguajes favoritos si alguien sabe cual es la razon por la cual me da ese error aunque sea utilizando otra solucion se los agradeceria mucho

Comment: Cual es el error exacto que te da?

Comment: El error es  el de la imagen por lo que entiendo el error esta en la funcion de la llamada PyArg _parseTuple por lo que entiendo este metodo convierte valores de python a valores de c pero por alguna extrana razon me da   el segmentatio fault

Comment: Es algo extrano ademas me dice que no encuentra el directorio pero eso esta raro ya que no he abierto ningun archivo

Comment: if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(archivo_user,"s",&filename)){ es en esta linea quiero suponer que es esto peor no se como arreglarlo